# Rails 5 Heroku - failed to detect set buildpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 5 app that I'm trying to push to Heroku.  The Heroku instance exists, git remotes are set up, etc.  However I'm getting an error that it can't detect the buildpack, although it is defined.  Any ideas?

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== xx Buildpack URL
heroku/ruby

$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
 ▸    The buildpack heroku/ruby is already set on your app.

$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1208, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1075/1075), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1208/1208), 25.04 MiB | 1.63 MiB/s, done.
Total 1208 (delta 634), reused 217 (delta 49)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to xx.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the configured buildpack cannot handle your application (as determined by its detection script), you will receive an error. For example, Heroku’s Ruby buildpack expects a Gemfile to be present in the root folder of an application to correctly identify its type, but if the buildpack of an application is set to heroku/ruby and no Gemfile is present, the application will fail to build. Try check if your Gemfile is present in the root folder of your project.

Comment: This is just from the Heroku docs... yes, I have a Gemfile. I did a fair amount of research before posting the question

Comment: Can you show your git repo? Very interesting question, so I wanted to try scanning your files. @tim5046